# ruby regex scan multiple match

Tags: ruby, regex, html-parsing

I am trying to get the text between two tag.

`<b> foo</b>bar<br/>` => `bar`

I tried using `'<b>asdasd</b>qwe<br/>'.scan(/<b>[a-zA-Z0-9]*<\/b>(.*)<br\/>/)` and it gives me proper result.

but when I try this :

```
'<b>exclude</b>op1<br/>exclude 2<b>exclude</b>op2<br/>exclude 2<b>exclude</b>op3<br/>exclude 2'.scan(/<b>[a-zA-Z0-9]*<\/b>(.*)<br\/>/) { |ele|
puts ele
}
```

It matches the first `<b>` tag and the last `<br/>` tag and returns the whole string I was expecting an array of matches

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `(.*)` to `(.*?)` to make it ungreedy

```
/<b>[a-zA-Z0-9]*<\/b>(.*?)<br\/>/
```

Test

```
[2] pry(main)> '<b>exclude</b>op1<br/>exclude 2<b>exclude</b>op2<br/>exclude 2<b>exclude</b>op3<br/>exclude 2'.scan(/<b>[a-zA-Z0-9]*<\/b>(.*?)<br\/>/) { |ele|
[2] pry(main)*   puts ele
[2] pry(main)* }  
op1
op2
op3
```

Comment: You cannot parse HTML with regex.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using regex on html use nokogiri:

```
Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(str).css('b').each do |b|
    puts b.next.text
end
```